How do you find packages and dependencies?
Trying to figure out how to even find where repos exist for yum installations.
I'm completely new to this yum install so, if yum install whatever does not work I don't know where to even look to see where it is coming from.
What repos are there out there that I can search for things.
In my case I am working in a sandbox environment with RHEL 8.x. When I try to run the yum install wine -y, it fails because it is missing dependencies.
I don't have any idea on how to find repos or to search those repos.
Any guidance for a newbie would be appreciated.
Thank you.


Trying to figure out how to even find where repos exist for yum installations.

Usually, you stick with Red Hat's repos, and EPEL (which you can enable by installing epel-release). Maybe even rpmfusion, if you need some stuff that can't be included in these for license reasons. But with these sources, the somewhat sensible amount of repositories is exhausted.
Third-party repos typically only contain a single piece of software (for example, a GPU driver, or the experimental version of some circuit editor or such). There's no sense amassing any such repos before you really know you need that specific piece of software.

I don't have any idea on how to find repos or to search those repos.

In the repos you've set up, you search using dnf search.
Searching for more repos: In short, you don't. You'll find an overwhelming majority of yum-installable packages are in the RHEL, EPEL or rpmfusion repositories.
If you need a distro that tries to package really "the world", then RHEL isn't the optimal choice – Red Hat packages with a strong focus on guarantees about long-term maintenance. Fedora might be more to your taste, which has much shorter-lived releases and a much larger package scope, whilst having the same tooling as RHEL, especially dnf (which has replaced yum a long-ish time ago).
(Also, RHEL8 is already a bit old when you want to start out today. RHEL 9 / AlmaLinux 9 exist. RHEL8 is a bit of a "cursed" release from a community point of view, [looong story] so it might be doubly hard to find packages for that. Which, I think, is especially the case for SDL2, which is most probably the missing dependency for wine on CentOS/RHEL 8? But to be fair, I found wine to be broken last time I looked, so maybe it still is. There seems to be a bit of a fault on RHEL's side involved.)
To not let you sit alone on the wine issue: You can dnf install -y flatpak; and then install Bottles from flathub. Flatpak is a mechanism for applications to bring all their own dependencies along. You lose a bit of integration, but it allows you to install software even on "hostile" packaging environments.

For people interested in installing SDL2 on RHEL8, it’s available in the CodeReady Linux Builder repositories — codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms.
